# Delphi remove first Y elements from TList

Tags: delphi

I have a TList with X amount of items and I need to remove the first Y items. How can I do this? The original TList should change. I don't want/need to create another TList.

Comment: You can try `TList<T>.RemoveRange(0, Y)`, which will remove Y items from specified index, in this case 0 for start.

Comment: Let's try to break this down. There is a single list instance (since you stipulate that you don't want to create another instance). You want to remove items from it. You also stipulate that this list instance must not be modified. How do you think this could be possible?

Comment: @Triber isn't that C#? I'm using Delphi, I searched and there's apparently a .DeleteRange() but in newer versions of Delphi and I'm using an older version

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, the list instance can be modified, I said "the original TList **should** change"

Comment: OK, I misread. Why don't you just remove item 0 in a loop that runs Y times?

Comment: As you already noticed that newer versions of Delphi provide a DeleteRange method, but your current version does not, I would have expected that you mention that together with the version it us going to be used in, so that we all don't have to run the same detour like you did.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I didn't though of that , thanks!

Comment: If performance matters, then it is better to move the items from Y to N-1 down to 0, and then reduce the count to N-Y

Comment: @nick What older version of Delphi are you using?

Comment: The first thing I would do if I faced this task would be to look at the documentation for [TList Methods](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.Classes.TList_Methods) to see if it had a method that allowed me to [Delete](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.Classes.TList.Delete) or [Remove](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.Classes.TList.Remove) items from it. If I was using the generic version of [TList](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.Generics.Collections.TList_Methods), I'd use its documentation instead.